# How to describe an existing JS library with multiple d.ts files, and export it using NPM

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I'm trying to describe our existing JS framework/library by using d.ts files, so we can have Intellisense and JSDoc in our front-end project, where the framework is referenced. The framework is exported as an NPM package.

I have the following file defined as my `"typings"` in `package.json`:

```
// ./src/index.d.ts
export = System;

declare namespace System {
    export class Greeter {
        greeting: string;

        constructor(params?: Greeter.Params = {});

        greet(): string;
    }

    declare namespace Greeter {
        export interface Params {
            greeting: string;
        }
    }
}
```

In the front-end, after installing the npm package `test-framework` locally, I can import and use it as follows, with full Intellisense and JSDoc comments showing:

```
import * as System from 'test-framework';

var t = new System.Greeter();
t.greet();
```

Now I would like to separate all my d.ts files. That way, I thought I would be able to import them in the index.d.ts file, and re-export them in the proper namespaces. I've tried all variants of import/export I could find. Based on the [TS declaration file documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), I would assume the following should work:

```
// ./src/index.d.ts
export = System;

declare namespace System {
    export { default as Greeter } from './test/greeter.d';
}


// ./src/test/greeter.d.ts
export class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(params?: Greeter.Params = {});

    greet(): string;
}

declare namespace Greeter {
    export interface Params {
        greeting: string;
    }
}

export = Greeter;
```

While the imported `System` will have a property `Greeter`, it does not recognize any further type information.

Is there any way to make something similar to the above work, or should I do this in a completely different way? Most solutions to similar problems I've found so far concern either two TS projects, or a single TS project. Ideally, we would be able to continue using JS (ES6) for both projects.